# Function overload dosen't works in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Guys how can I overload the query function of my code. I specify the return type but it doesn't works.

```
export class QueryService {

  _url = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+':8080/api';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  function query():Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get<any>(this._url+'/query/');
  }

  function query(userName:string, orgName:string):Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get<any>(this._url+'/query/'+userName+'/'+orgName);
  }

  querySingle(cnr){
    return this._http.get(this._url+'/querySingle/'+cnr)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work as in C++ or other languages. You must create multiple overload function declaration and one general implementation.

```js
export class QueryService {

  _url = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+':8080/api';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  query(): Observable<any>;
  query(userName:string, orgName:string): Observable<any>;
  query(userName?: string, orgName?: string): Observable<any> {
    if (userName && orgName) {
      return this._http.get<any>(this._url+'/query/'+userName+'/'+orgName);
    }
    
    return this._http.get<any>(this._url+'/query/');
  }

  querySingle(cnr){
    return this._http.get(this._url+'/querySingle/'+cnr)
  }
}
```